# Quintus engine,Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined

Tags: html, game-engine

I'm following the quintus tutorial on http://html5quintus.com/,
and do some code,
this is my code:

```
var Q = Quintus().include("Sprites").setup(
    {
        width:800,
        height:600
    }
    );
    Q.Sprite.extend("Player",{
        init:function(p){
            this._super(p,{ sheet:"superman" });
            this.add('2d');
            }
    });
    Q.load("sprites.json,sprites.png",function()
    {
        var man=new Q.Player();
        Q.gameLoop(function(dt){
            man.render(Q.ctx);
        });
    });
```

and in the browser I got this error:
    Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined

it's weird because the error occurs in `quintus-all.js` on line `3520`.
can somebody help me? 
 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot to compile your sprite sheet:

```
Q.load("sprites.json,sprites.png",function()
{
    // Add compileSheets
    Q.compileSheets("sprites.png","sprites.json");

    var man=new Q.Player();
    Q.gameLoop(function(dt){
        man.render(Q.ctx);
    });
});
```